# Doctrine encrypt column

Tags: php, symfony, encryption, doctrine-orm

Using `Doctrine 2` and `Symfony 3`, is there an easy way to automatically encrypt a column?

Ideally, it should work like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="secret", type="string")
 * @Encrypted
 */
private $secret;
```

Or, is there an official (or very popular) bundle that supports encryption and?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this bundle

https://github.com/ambta/DoctrineEncryptBundle

Example:

```
/**
 * @Encrypt
 */
protected $secret;
```

Comment: I have used It and it works fine, so there are other bundle if isn't good for you, but try It

Comment: Remember that this bundle, like the one it forks, still uses ext-mcrypt, which is deprecated starting with PHP 7.1.

A better option would be something that requires OpenSSL, but until now there are no bundles for Symfony that support that.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if there's any truth to it, I'm no crypto expert, but [this repo's](https://github.com/michaeldegroot/DoctrineEncryptBundle) author (Michael de Groot) claims the "ambta" version is not secure and offers his own as a replacement.

> This is an fork from the original bundle created by ambta which can be found here: ambta/DoctrineEncryptBundle
>
> This bundle has updated security by not rolling it's own encryption and using verified standardized library's from the field.
>
> ambta/DoctrineEncryptBundle is **not** secured, It uses old crypto functions and programming mistakes like supplying a IV in ECB mode (which does nothing)

Thought I'd leave that here in case there's truth to it as I'm currently looking around for the same functionality.

---

### UPDATE 3

(2018-12-16)

Been working on our own Encrypt module the past few days. So if you've come here with hopes for a Zend Framework 3 + Doctrine module, [have a look at mine](https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-encrypt).

The standard PHP 7.2 Sodium library and Paragonie's [halite](https://github.com/paragonie/halite) module's are used to handle the actual en-/decryption.

Encryption en hashing of properties is done in the [Doctrine Events](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html) `onFlush` for storing (encryption & hashing) and `postLoad` for decryption.

Encryption and hashing of properties are enabled with `@Encrypted` and `@Hashed` Annotation respectively.

Additional:

- Encryption & Decryption Adapter, Subscriber & Service (for non-Event usage) are provided, using aliases, so you may override these to provide your own
- Supply just `@Encrypted` or `@Hashed` to enable usage.
- `@Encrypted` takes a `type` option to attempt to return that type upon decryption (`postLoad`)

---

**Note**: Updated the above (2018-12-16) to remove link to the one we created at work and encryption/hashing of data is important. Changed the link to my own repo as I'm leaving the company soon and, in agreement, I'll be taking over that repo, though I've also updated it with the additional Services. The company one (see answer history) *is being deprecated* in favor of mine.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for you to use a bundle or the lifecycle of doctrine. 
To do this you can create your own doctrine custom type and create an doctrine eventlister and inject a crypter in this class. In your custom type you have access to this eventlister to get the crypter and now you can encrypt into database and decrypt from database.

It is a small codebase which is perfect and simple!

```
<?php

namespace PaymentBundle\Doctrine\Type;

use Foobar\Encryption\Aes256OpensslCrypter;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use FooBundle\Doctrine\EventListener\Crypter;

class Encrypted extends Type
{
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $platform->getClobTypeDeclarationSQL($fieldDeclaration);
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return 'encrypted';
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform): string
    {
        if ($value === '') {
            return '';
        }

        $crypter = $this->getCrypter($platform);

        return $crypter->encrypt($value);
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform): string
    {
        if ($value === '') {
            return '';
        }

        $crypter = $this->getCrypter($platform);

        return $crypter->decrypt($value);
    }

    private function getCrypter(AbstractPlatform $platform): Aes256OpensslCrypter
    {
        /** @var array $listCrypterListener */
        $listCrypterListener = $platform->getEventManager()->getListeners('crypter');
        /** @var Crypter $crypterListener */
        $crypterListener = array_shift($listCrypterListener);

        return $crypterListener->getCrypter();
    }
}
```

```
// Foo.orm.yml
Entity\Foo:
  type: entity
  table: foo
  options:
    collate:
      utf8_unicode_ci
  id:
    id:
      id: true
      type: string
      length: 36
  fields:
    details:
      nullable: true
      type: encrypted
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }

// Symfony services.yml
Foobar\Encryption\Aes256OpensslCrypter: ["%crypter_secret_key%"]
FooBundle\Doctrine\EventListener\Crypter:
  arguments:
    - '@Foobar\Encryption\Aes256OpensslCrypter'
  tags:
    - {name: doctrine.event_listener, event: crypter}
```

Comment: Before you update your answer, please read the following: While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)